# SQL Query to get the compliance status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to get the following query constructed

I got a table called client_vendor as follows. This stores the details of answers provided by client against a vendor for 4 questions.

**client_vendor**

```
create table client_vendor(clientid int, vendorid int, q1 varchar(1), q2 varchar(1), q2 varchar(1), q4  varchar(1));


insert into client_vendor values(100,1,"Y","N","N","");
insert into client_vendor values(101,1,"Y","Y","N","Y");
insert into client_vendor values(102,1,"Y","Y","","");
```

The client can answer either Y or N or not give a response to the questions asked.
Here `clientid=100` has answered as follows `q1=Y`,`q2=N`,`q3=N`,`q4=""` against `vendorid=1`.

We have another table called vendor_compliance

**vendor_compliance**

```
create table vendor_compliance(vendorid, q1 varchar(1), q2 varchar(1), q2 varchar(1), q4  varchar(1));

insert into vendor_question values(1,"Y","","N","");
```

This table indicates compliance,if the client answers for the questions the expected values.

Here if the client answers to `q1=Y` and `q3=N` then he is compliant. The answers to q2 and q3 are irrelevant for `vendorid=1` to indicate compliance.

I wish to create a query which will show up the clientid, vendorid and the compliance status as follows

```
clientid,vendorid,compliance_status
100    ,1       ,compliant
101    ,1       ,compliant
102    ,1       ,non-compliant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` with some `case` logic:

```
select cv.*,
       (case when vc.q1 <> cv.q1 and vc.q1 <> '' then 'non-compliant'
             when vc.q2 <> cv.q2 and vc.q2 <> '' then 'non-compliant'
             when vc.q3 <> cv.q3 and vc.q3 <> '' then 'non-compliant'
             when vc.q4 <> cv.q4 and vc.q4 <> '' then 'non-compliant'
             else 'compliant'
        end) as compliance
from client_vendor cv join
     vendor_compliance vc
     on cv.vendorid = vc.vendorid
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset has a large number of questions columns, you might want to consider unpivot and aggregation:

```
select 
    cv.clientid,
    cv.vendorid,
    max(case when q.qcv <> q.qvd and q.qvd <> '' then 'non-compliant' else 'compliant' end) compliance_status
from client_vendor cv
inner join vendor_compliance vd on vd.vendorid = cv.vendorid
cross apply (values (cv.q1, vd.q1), (cv.q2, vd.q2), (cv.q3, vd.q3), (cv.q4, vd.q4)) as q(qcv, qvd)
group by cv.clientid, cv.vendorid
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb505808d5ff8c00a929fd3508bc9715)**:

```
clientid | vendorid | compliance_status
-------: | -------: | :----------------
     100 |        1 | compliant        
     101 |        1 | compliant        
     102 |        1 | non-compliant
```